# Why does this string comparision mysql query return nothing?

Tags: mysql, string, sql-like

I execute the following:

```
SELECT url FROM mytable WHERE 1
```

result: url: 'http://www.ciao.es/Epson_Stylus_S22__2007613'

Everything ok by now...but when I do:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE url = 'http://www.ciao.es/Epson_Stylus_S22__2007613'
```

I get nothing!!!

I tried using LIKE, changing the quotes, etc...
what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have '' in your url field? I mean are u getting result in with '' like 'http://www.ciao.es/Epson_Stylus_S22__2007613'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having ' ' in your table field url .So if you are querying you will get output like this:
 'http://www.ciao.es/Epson_Stylus_S22__2007613' (with in single quote)
SO 
Write in this way:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE url = "'http://www.ciao.es/Epson_Stylus_S22__2007613'"
```

Or remove single quote from table.